# Calculate possible permutations/combinations of a set of unique values without repetition or reflection

Tags: permutations, combinations

Let's say I have a set of five unique values: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

I want to calculate the number of possible combinations of these values without allowing any of the values to be repeated, which I understand is easily calculated as `5! = 120`.

However, I *also* want the calculation to exclude "reflected" combinations of these values - *e.g.*, `1,2,3,4,5` is effectively the same as `5,4,3,2,1`, and `2,4,5,3,1` is a reflection of `1,3,5,4,2`.

Is there a "simple" formula to expresses this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Simply divide the result you obtained by two.  Notice that *every* outcome you are wanting to count was counted twice (*once with a smaller number in front and once with a larger number in front*)

More formally, you can explain this by way of either the Shepherd's Principle (to count # of sheep in a field but can't make out bodies from one another since they are too fuzzy, instead count the legs and divide by four) or if you want to get fancy you can use [Pólya Enumeration Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem) or you can use [The Lemma which is not Burnside's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma).

Comment: Thank you for that. I had a *feeling* it was that simple, but I kept going in circles arguing with myself.